# Shifting of minimas in transmission spectrum due to phase transition

Tags: solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, phase-transition, phase-diagram

Given is the following transmission spectrum of heptadecane for different temperatures:
[image]

Approximately at $T = 294.5\,\text{K}$, there is a phase transition from liquid to solid.

Now, one can see that the minimas of the transition spectrum shift towards lower wave numbers when the phase transition occurs.

It is obvious that this occurs due to changing interactions between the molecules, but why exactly this happens?